# VB6 and VB.NET interoperability using com.visible

Tags: vb.net, vb6, com-interop

Please see the code below:

```
   Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices  
        Public Class TestClass
            <ComVisible(True)> _
            Public Function Hello() As String
                Return "Hello Ian"
            End Function

            Public Function Goodbye() As String
                Return "Goodbye Ian"
            End Function   
    End Class
```

I have created the Type Library using Regasm and I have added a reference to the TLB in a VB6 project.  The code for VB6 is below:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim tc As TestClass
Set tc = New TestLibrary.TestClass
MsgBox (tc.Hello)
MsgBox (tc.GoodBye)
End Sub
```

I do not understand why the message prints the value of: tc.Goodbye as this is not visible.

I believe it is because the default value is true.  Is there a way to set the default value to false.

Comment: The entire class is visible, you would not be able to create the TestClass object in VB6 otherwise.  Which trumps visibility of methods of course.  It is not that Goodbye isn't visible, it is that the attribute on Hello just doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Hans Passant, if you do not want a class to be visible to COM then I assume you put in the attribute and set it to false.  I assume you can pick and choose which functions and classes to expose.